# Setting derivative to 0 when minimizing expected loss over possible data samples

Tags: statistics, loss-function, optimization

Suppose, given $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, you want $\theta$, which is the solution of

$$
\text{argmin}_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_a[L(\theta;x,a)]
$$

where $a \sim \mathcal{N}(x,\Sigma)$ and $L$ measures a (convex) loss for the parameters $\theta$ at data $a$ which are to be sampled around $x$.

Can you start by setting $\nabla_\theta L = 0$ instead of $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}[L] = 0$ as usual?

That is, is it appropriate to set $\nabla_\theta L = 0$, then take the expectation, and solve for $\theta$?

My concern is that this technique bypasses what I see as a "correct" set of steps, which crucially deduce all results from the initial supposition that $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}[L] = 0$:

- Suppose that $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}[L] = 0$
- Establish that $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}[L] = \mathbb{E}[\nabla_\theta L]$
- Compute $\mathbb{E}[\nabla_\theta L]$, set it equal to $0$, and solve for $\theta$.

If you begin only with $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}[L] = 0$, I think you cannot necessarily deduce that $\nabla_\theta L = 0$.

I guess it would be OK if you establish that $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}[L] = \mathbb{E}[\nabla_\theta L]$ since then $\nabla_\theta \mathbb{E}[L] = \mathbb{E}[\nabla_\theta L] = \mathbb{E}[0]=0$ means $\theta$ is the solution of $\text{argmin}_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_a[L(\theta;x,a)]$

Comment: Are you aiming for an analytic solution or for an algorithm to approximate the optimum (such as gradient descent)?

Comment: @Broele I'm aiming for an analytic solution.